# Python tornado - [Errno 113] No route to host

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I have an error in tornado framework and I can't find any solution at all.

Can anyone had similar problem or know what is the couse of this?

```
WARNING:tornado.general:error on read
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 644, in _handle_read
    pos = self._read_to_buffer_loop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 614, in _read_to_buffer_loop
    if self._read_to_buffer() == 0:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 726, in _read_to_buffer
    chunk = self.read_from_fd()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 1005, in read_from_fd
    chunk = self.socket.recv(self.read_chunk_size)
error: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

I'm usign Python 2.6.6, should I upgrade it to 2.7.9 ?

Comment: It simpy means you can't reach the host from your network. It is related to network configuration.

Comment: I can't figure out when it happens. I have about 300 users  that are connected to tornado via websocket and I send them some part of information. Usually it works, but sometimes I get this kind of error.

Should I ping socket client before sending bunch of information? 

However this error happens when tornado receives information, not sends. Am I correct?